# Regex for amounts in euro

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to find a regex expression that select only the amounts (in euros) so the value needs to be preceded by a `€` or `euros` and that after the `,` we have the pennies, there can be spaces or dots as well.

```
7 967  59 €
- 9847, 48 euros à titre de rappel de salaire sur le bonus de l'année 2012,
 - 1929, 78 euros à titre de rappel de salaire sur le bonus de l'année 2013,
  - 129 689, 78 euros à titre de solde d'indemnité conventionnelle de licenciement,
- 1098 euros au titre du paiement du DIF,
é à 20 892, 05 euros, il ressort des pi
le de 27 084, 26 euros
ée à 26 395, 10 euros, hors bo
 de 129 689, 78 euros,
6.000 € au titre des dommages et intérêts pour licenciement sans cause réelle et sérieuse,
 1.510 € au titre de l'indemnité compensatrice de préavis,
 151 € au titre des congés payés y afférents, 739 € au titre de l'indemnité de licenciement,
 656,19 € au titre de l'indemnité due au titre de la non rémunération de la période de mise à pied conservatoire,
 65,61 € au titre des congés payés afférents,
 2.000 € au titre de  59 € au titre de <span class="highlight_underline">l'indemnité légale de licenciement</span>
2014,7 967, 59 € au titre de <span class="highlight_underline">l'indemnité légale de licenciement</span>
rappel de salaires de janvier 2007 au 7 mars 2007 3.708,34 €
SECTION B N° 419 425 426 427 428 429 430 432 433 434 436 441 442 443 444 446 467 571 572
```

I came up with this:

```
(\d.+\d+)(?:\s(?:euros?|€))
```

But it isn't as accurate as it should.

Can someone help me ??

EDIT:

@Wiktor Stribiżew gave me :

```
(\d[\d.\s,]*)(?:\s(?:euro|€))
```

which is close but with this examples:

```
2014,7 967, 59 €
```

it takes also the `2014,`

and with `49715 11000158926 101,30 €`

it takes `49715 11000158926`. Numbers are limited to groups of 3.

and with `2007 3.708,34 €`

it shouldn't take the `2007` as well

Edit 2:

Thanks for the answer, but it seems not to work in my python script :

```
import regex
sentences_pd = pd.read_csv('sampled_amounts.csv', names=["text"])
sentences_pd.head()
print([(regex.findall("\b((?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[,.\s]\d{3})*)(?:[,.\s]*\d+)?)\s(?:euros?|€)", x)) for x in sentences_pd['text']])
```

the text column looks like:

[image]

It gives me an empty array

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LPXcI/1) or [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/39Oj35/1).

Comment: Sorry the example wasn't specific enough, question edited! @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I'd go for the first "demo" from @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @Adriano well it doesn't work! see the new larger example

Comment: Maybe [`(\d[\d.\s,]*)(?:\s(?:euro|€))`](https://regex101.com/r/0LPXcI/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew we're close!! question edited ;)

Comment: Well, try [`\b((?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[,.\s]\d{3})*)(?:[,.\s]*\d+)?)(?:\s(?:euro|€))`](https://regex101.com/r/0LPXcI/4)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks mate, works like a charm! You can answer the question :)

Comment: Good one Wiktor, I added another bit https://regex101.com/r/0LPXcI/5

Comment: @Adriano Yeah, I removed the redundant non-capturing group from the end. The `s?` is not important as I understand only the number itself is what OP needs to get in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\b((?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[,.\s]\d{3})*)(?:[,.\s]*\d+)?)\s(?:euros?|€)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LPXcI/7)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `((?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[,.\s]\d{3})*)(?:[,.\s]*\d+)?)` - Group 1

  - `(?:` - an alternation group start

    - `\d+` - 1+ digits
    - `|` - or
    - `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
    - `(?:[,.\s]\d{3})*` - 0+ sequences of

      - `[,.\s]`  - 1 whitespace, `,` or `.`
      - `\d{3}` - 3 digits
  - `)` - end of the alternation group
  - `(?:[,.\s]*\d+)?` - an optional group of

    - `[,.\s]*` - 0+ whitespaces, `,` or `.`
    - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?:euros?|€)` - either `euro`, `euros` or `€`

Comment: Why it doesn't work in my python script? I'm writing `print([(regex.findall("\b((?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[,.\s]\d{3})*)(?:[,.\s]*\d+)?)\s(?:euros?|€)", x)) for x in sentences_pd['text']])` and it gives me empty arrays while other regex work ?

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud Use raw string literals for regexes: `pattern = r"\b((?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[,.\s]\d{3})*)(?:‌​[,.\s]*\d+)?)\s(?:eu‌​ros?|€)"`

Comment: @BaptisteArnaud If you specified a Python tag, I'd post the usage example when posting. Please add relevant information. The regex pattern in the regex answers is a sequence of literal chars that you should "encode" correctly in each language of your choice. Sometimes, you just need to double the backslashes (if you do not use raw string literals) and somethimes, you do not have to (if you use raw string literals).

Comment: If you are using it in pandas, you may use `sentences_pd['text'].str.extractall(r'....pattern here...')` or suchlike.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, I created this Regex for Spanish prices (€). The conditions are:

```
1.- The decimal point with 2 exact decimals
2.- Decimals can not be "00"
3.- The point of a thousand is not admitted. In my case the prices do not exceed 999 €
4.- The front and back spaces are not allowed
5.- One ¨0¨ is not admitted in front of a whole number

Regex: ^((0\,(?!00)\d{2})|([1-9]\d*(\,(?!00)\d{2})?)|0)$
```

Allowed values:

- 0
- 1234
- 0,10
- 12,34

Values not allowed:

- 0,00
- 0,1
- 1234 (space at the beginning)
- 1234 (space at the end)
- 12,00
- 01,23
- 12,345
- 1.234