# Regex: Extract amounts in Euro

Tags: python, regex, matching

I need a Python regex which extracts amounts in €. For example:

- 99 €
- 99.99 €
- 99,99 Euro
- 100

I got inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156680/regex-for-amounts-in-euro). Based on this I have build the following regex:

```
^((\d[\d.\s,]*)(?:\s(?:euro|€|Euro))|\d)$
```

If you like to see more examples, please see the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MzR8EF/1). The regex isn't finished yet. The problem that I face is that it doesn't match the full string.

Maybe you can help me with that? I am not an expert in regex!

Comment: Do you want to match `100`, without any currency indicator?  If so, then how do we know the currency of a number without a label?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/MzR8EF/2

Comment: Yes, it is fine if the user inputs only the raw number. Since I asked the user to specify his amount in €, I can expect him to enter the value not in $ or Yen but in €.

Comment: What about those trailing spaces in your example. Are those a typo?

Comment: I wonder if someone would input €100 instead.

Comment: @JvdV No, they are by purpose. The regex is used in my chatbot. It is possible that the user inputs some whitespace after the amount.

Comment: @user56700: Good point. Never thought about this. This could be possible!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much. Your demo works perfectly. Maybe wen can add the example made by user56700: ``€ 100``

Comment: One more question. Why do you want to capture the whole string in a 1st capture group? Are these also part of larger strings then? Your own attempt suggest it isn't since you used start/end tags. If so, then you'd simply discard the 1st capture group and use the whole match. For example [this](https://regex101.com/r/jSdKga/1) assuming people won't write `€ 100 Euro` or something.

Comment: The goal is to captuar the whole string as Wiktor has done it. The Bot asks the user for an amount. The user inputs the amount and the regex picks up the amount and validates it.  The example of @WiktorStribiżew basicaly works. The only nice little detail would be to add the example given by user56700: ``€ 100``

Comment: But why do you want the whole string captured in a group if you match from start-end tags in the 1st place? Nevermind, if it works it works I suppose =)

Comment: `^(?:€ *)?(\d(?:[. ,]*\d)*)(?: (?:euro|€|Euro))? *$`

Comment: Awesome, this is the perfect solution. All of you, thank you very much!!! 
PS: Wiktor, I send you a PM. Did you read it? Not sure if I did it right.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please post an answer for us to vote and to help others in the future. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?:€ *)?(\d(?:[. ,]*\d)*)(?: (?:[eE]uro|€))? *$
```

Note: if you test against standalone strings, you can replace all literal spaces with `\s` (any one whitespace) or `\s+` (one or more whitespaces).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:€ *)?` - an optional sequence of `€` and zero or more spaces
- `(\d(?:[. ,]*\d)*)`
- `(?: (?:[eE]uro|€))?` - an optional sequence of a space (add `*` after it to make it match zero or more spaces), `euro`, `Euro` or `€`
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ODKgww/1).